# SQL division by zero

Tags: sql

i have a query that in a sub query calculates amount by dividing two of the columns. I get this error that i have division by zero, but actually i don't have 0 or NULL values. Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT ISNULL((IznosIni/VrednostIni),0)
from  plPlataF f1 
where plPresmetka_id in 
    (select plPresmetka_id from plPresmetka where f_vlezno=1 and Kod ='01') 
and f1.plPlataS_id=s.plPlataS_id) 
FROM plPlataS s 
WHERE plPlataH_Id = 171
```

when i run this query (i only concatenate the two values with '---' in between)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),IznosIni)+'---'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),VrednostIni)
from  plPlataF f1 
where plPresmetka_id in 
    (select plPresmetka_id from plPresmetka where f_vlezno=1 and Kod ='01') 
and f1.plPlataS_id=s.plPlataS_id) 
FROM plPlataS s 
WHERE plPlataH_Id = 171
```

i get results :

```
32414.00---168.00 
37613.00---168.00 
31341.00---168.00 
49148.00---168.00 
110507.00---168.00 
36601.00---168.00 
37895.00---168.00 
59699.00---168.00 
43978.00---168.00 
50991.00---168.00 
36601.00---168.00 
48087.00---168.00 
45921.00---168.00 
59499.00---168.00 
37613.00---168.00 
37613.00---168.00 
34850.00---168.00 
33632.00---168.00 
33632.00---168.00
```

There is no 0 anywhere!!!
Can someone please help i don't understand what the problem might be.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the output of just `SELECT IznosIni, VrednostIni FROM ...`

Comment: Please indicate your DBMS in tags (is it Oracle?).

Comment: for this query SELECT IznosIni,VrednostIni 
 from  plPlataF f1 
 where plPresmetka_id in 
  (select plPresmetka_id from plPresmetka where f_vlezno=1 and Kod ='01') 
 and f1.plPlataS_id IN (SELECT plPlataS_Id FROM dbo.plPlataS WHERE  plPlataH_Id = 171)

result is 

IznosIni VrednostIni
32414.00 168.00
37613.00 168.00
31341.00 168.00
49148.00 168.00
110507.00 168.00
36601.00 168.00
37895.00 168.00
59699.00 168.00
43978.00 168.00
50991.00 168.00
36601.00 168.00
48087.00 168.00
45921.00 168.00
59499.00 168.00
37613.00 168.00
37613.00 168.00
34850.00 168.00
33632.00 168.00
33632.00 168.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `ISNULL`, I'm guessing this is TSQL. You should always take into account on division about the possibility of dividing by zero. You can use `NULLIF` for this:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT ISNULL((IznosIni/NULLIF(VrednostIni,0)),0)
from  plPlataF f1 
where plPresmetka_id in 
    (select plPresmetka_id from plPresmetka where f_vlezno=1 and Kod ='01') 
and f1.plPlataS_id=s.plPlataS_id) 
FROM plPlataS s 
WHERE plPlataH_Id = 171
```

Comment: This is a serious question.  Why would you make it zero if null and then set it back to null if 0?

Comment: i can replace  ISNULL((IznosIni/NULLIF(VrednostIni,1)),0)

Comment: @user1166147 - The `NULLIF` only converts to `NULL` to avoid dividing by zero, thous converting the value of the division to `NULL` on that case. Then, the `ISNULL` converts that expression to zero, avoiding succesfully the problem. Its not like I'm applying those functions on the same column (otherwise it wouldn't make much sense)

Comment: @user1489128 - That would work because you don't actually have a `VrednostIni` value of zero, but if you do, it would fail, and the result if you actually have a valuee of 1 would not be the right value

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your RDBMS is evaluating the division before it applied the where filter. This is entirely legal.

You need to guard against that possibility like this:

```
case when VrednostIni = 0 then null else ISNULL((IznosIni/VrednostIni),0 end
```